# What systems are there to manage backend and front end logic/validation?

Tags: php, javascript, validation

I'm just wondering how people working in teams manage the relationship between the logic and validation in the backend, say in php, and the exact same logic and validation in the front end, for example in JavaScript?

Ideally, the final say should be given by the backend, but in order to make the application more accesible, it would be good to mimic as much as possible in the front end using JavaScript. I'm obviously trying to minimise duplication of code, and as projects get bigger, I'm finding it harder to manage how the front end stuff gets 'copied' from the backend stuff. The danger is that, as they're not tightly coupled, sometimes the front-end validation can get 'out of sync' with the backend - especially when there's a rogue JavaScript developer who thinks they've got a better way of doing some validation!

Does anyone have any insight?

**EDIT**

To be more concise, my question is really about how teams of people manage the 'papertrail' when it comes to duplication of logic (or how the front end access the backend as suggested by Fanis below), rather than the actual implementation. For example, do you leave comments in the backend code saying "front end copies/accesses this bit" or is there a more 'professional' way to keep track of what's doing what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whichever part actually uses the data should be the one with the final say, ie the backend, and it should have the strictest validation rules. For me validation in the front end is there to improve user experience, so that the user gets faster feedback on what's wrong with his input without waiting for a page reload. I would be ok with the front end having a small subset of the most generic validation rules (ie fields empty, malformed email addresses etc) and let the back end do any heavy lifting (eg duplicate entries detection).

However, if you need to bring full validation to the front end, consider this:

- make the backend's validation decoupled from any form submission logic
- setup a separate endpoint (API) that will receive data, perform validation, and echo out any errors or "ok"
- have the front end pass via ajax the form data into that endpoint and return any errors to display
- if all ok then let the form submission go ahead

This way you only have 1 copy of the validation rules, in your backend.

Note that you would be doing the validation twice, and if it's expensive (ie duplicates detection with heuristics over a large data set) perhaps that's not desireable. You could solve that by storing the form data in the user's session during the first validation if no error was found. Then when the form is actually submitted the backend won't re-validate it.

This should degrade nicely if javascript is not enabled.

Comment: As you say, using an API to access the same validation logic the backend uses sounds kind of expensive, but I've seen whole websites running on DOM manipulation through AJAX, so maybe it wouldn't be too bad. I like the idea of storing the result of the first validation in the session...

Comment: If you decouple validation from form submission processing it should be trivial to implement, and by storing validation results you avoid the double checks. Think of it as pre-approved form submissions :)

Comment: The AJAX idea is a good one but it's not do good on slow connections, where a connection to the server after each form

Comment: The AJAX idea is a good one but it's not so good on slow connections, where a connection to the server after each form field can get annoying. Perhaps the backend validation could be configured to return a set of statistics (max length if field etc.) when the page loads. This could be converted to JS and a JS function could use the stats to do a bit of validation offline. You wouldn't be able to do "already exists" kinds of validation this way, though.

Comment: It doesn't have to be triggered after every form field, only the ones you care about such as email and username. If the connection is slow and the frontend validation doesn't have time to complete before the user actually hits submit, you could interrupt the form submit and wait for the validation to complete, proceeding if no errors, or just submit it and let the backend do its job. Frontend validation is just there to give a better user experience, it probably shouldn't block usual form submission as a fallback.

Answer (score 2):

have you looked at nodejs lately? with a bit of work and the appropriate framework (like, mootools) you can run literally the same validation classes both client and server side.

Comment: Do you have any examples at all? I had a quick skim through but don't see anything like you suggest?

Comment: sure - i saw this recently at the london ajax group meets. to quote from the author Piotr Zalewa (of mozilla): Here is a quick and dirty almost MVC written in 3-4 hours for my talk at London Ajax - https://github.com/zalun/London-Ajax-Users-Group---Node-and-Mootools/tree/1-with_frontend_js and the PDFs: http://piotr.zalewa.info/downloads/LAUG-Server_Side_JS_and_MooTools.pdf - he had never used nodejs before giving the presentation.